# Assign DocuSign BrandID in CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates API method

Tags: c#, docusignapi

We have created 2 DocuSign Custom Branding and enabled in DocuSign Demo Portal.

In DocuSign API C#, There is no option to assign the DocuSign BrandID when creating the envelope. Please let us know how we can enable this option and assign the BrandID when creating the envelope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is listed in [DocuSign's SOAP API guide](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/documentation), both the PDF format and the Online version.

You need to set the `BrandId` property in your envelope where the value is set to a valid brandId of one your branding profiles you've created.

Using the C# examples from the SOAP API guide, it would look something like this:

```
// Create the envelope content 
DocuSignWeb.Envelope envelope = new DocuSignWeb.Envelope();
envelope.Subject = "Subject";
envelope.EmailBlurb = "Email content";
envelope.Recipients = new DocuSignWeb.Recipient[] { recipient };
envelope.AccountId = accountId;

envelope.BrandId = brandId;  // where brandId is a valid api brand id
```

---

You can find out what your brand ids are either through the Console or through the API.

1. To see through the Console:

   - Login, click you Profile icon and go to the `Preferences` -> `Branding`, then click *Edit* on one of your brands and go to the `Info` page.  There you'll see the **API Brand Id** value.
2. To retrieve through the SOAP API:

   - Make the  [Get Account Brands API](http://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/APIGuide.htm#Administrative%20Group/GetAccountBrands.htm) call.